# Eclipse: How to update View when file open/switch to new file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to update the view content when I switch or open a new file in the Eclipse project explorer. I tried using "IResourceChangeListener" but it is not triggered (only on changed on the file itself). I also looked looked at https://www.wideskills.com/eclipse-plugin-tutorial (specific on the view part), and Eclipse forums, without success. I thought it would be easy thing... Any Ideas ? small code example will be great !

Comment: You probably need to use `IPartListener` to see parts being activated.

Comment: do you have some example ? or code reference ?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching (and based on @greg-449 comment) I was able to generate a small example that get notified when a new file is opened and is currently visible in the editor:
in the derived ViewPart class:

```
    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    .
    .
    .


    workbench.getPartService().addPartListenr(new IPartListener2() {
            public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
                String part = partRef.toString();
                showMessage("partOpened is " + part);
            }
            
            public void partVisible(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
                String part = partRef.toString();
                showMessage("partVisible is " + part);
            }
        });
    }
```